# iOS 7 status bar color during push animation.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, statusbar, ios7

My app has a solid gray navigation bar, and to fit with the iOS 7 design, want the status bar to be the same color.

To do this, I've set `edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone` and `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES` and have `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `YES` in my plist.  To create the gray color for the status bar, I've set the background color of my `MainWindow` to be the gray color.  This works well except when there's a push or pop animation.  During the animation, the status bar flashes color and looks like it has double the intensity of gray.  When the animation ends, it changes back to the correct gray color.

Does anyone know what might be happening?  Should I be setting the status bar color to match the navigation bar color differently?

Comment: Did you try slowing down the animation in the simulator so that you could observe the animation? You might see something obvious when you do.

Comment: @dtrotzjr, I did.  The only animation that slows down is the push animation of the nav bar.  Both the push animation of the screen and the status bar don't slow down.

Comment: But even with the normal animation speed, it looks like the status bar color from the view controller being pushed overlaps with the bottom view controller's status bar color, hence causing double the intensity of gray.  Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using an background image or a tint color to set the background of the navigation bar?

If you use a background image (which it sounds like since you have a solid gray background), you need to make sure it is 64 points tall (128 pixel in retina). If you use the old iOS 6 dimensions (44 points), iOS 7 will fall back and not have it include the status bar.

For details of this behavior, check out *Table 5-1, "Treatment of resizable background images for bars at the top of the screen"* [in the iOS 7 transition documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html).

Also, if this is the case you shouldn't need to set the `edgesForExtendedLayout`, `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` and `View controller-based status bar appearance`. You might need it for other stuff - but not for this.

If you want to still support iOS 6, you need to have two different background images, one of iOS 7 and above and a legacy version of iOS 6 and below. That should get you the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I actually have a custom UINavigationBar and override it's drawRect method, filling the rect with the gray color using CGContextSetFillColor and CGContextFillRect.

Comment: I switched from drawRect to using a background image and everything animates properly now.  The side effect is that there's now the default ios7 1px line at the bottom of the nav bar, but that shouldn't be that big of an issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, for answer completeness, to remove the shadow of the nav bar, you can set the shadow image to an empty image.